# Is it possible that a git merge without conflicts breaks application functionalities?

Tags: git, merge

Few times, I merge a branch into mine, fix the conflicts with close attention and still some functionalities of my application are broken. It is probably my bad trying wrongly to resolve the conflicts, but is it possible that in some cases that git did not raised conflicts but still merge the files in a wrong manner?

Let's say I have the following scenario:

- Two giant branches that differs a lot.
- Most of the tests of the branches are common but some differ.
- I merge these branches and it merges without conflicts.

Is it possible in some cases that some tests are broken after the merge?

Comment: Yes, solving conflicts has no guarantee about the correctness of the logic, it just lets you decide which logic goes over, that's why you should run the new deployment against unit tests and integration tests.

Comment: I would actually phrase this differently, not as a question but rather as a statement: the surprising thing is how often a `git merge` *doesn't* break things. Git is not intelligent; `git merge` is following some very simple text rules that take three versions of a file, compare those three line-by-line, and combine the resulting two diffs into a single diff that Git can apply to the merge base copy of some file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes it happens. One easy example is if there are API changes on a branch. All the calls on that branch will be adjusted for the new API. How about in *another* branch, a new call to the adjusted-on-the-other-branch function/method be added? If you merge both branches, it is very unlikely that you will get a conflict out of this API change..... but the code will probably be broken because the *new* call is still using the old API.

If you have an amazing set of unit/integration tests, this problem would be detected before wrapping up the merge. Say, I merge. I test.... if I see that something is broken, I fix it, I amend the merge revision and then I can move on.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Are there many other examples like that where the non conflicted code might still be broken after the merge?

Comment: Well.... moved a file and adding a link (original path) to it in another branch? There you go.... another simple example. :-) And there are others, I'm sure.